# What kind of Mic do I need to connect to a pots telephone line to speak?

Tags: voltage

Can someone tell me what kind of microphone or mouthpiece I can use to connect across a pots telephone line in order to send dtmf tones ( no voice ) dtmf only. Can I use a regular mic or does it have to be a certain type, I am using a 300 ohm resistor to hold open the line automatic and I need to know what kind of mic i need or if i will need any additional components to make this work  thanks

Comment: How are you generating the tones? Why can't you just use a fully built phone and play the tones into the mouthpiece?

Comment: this is for an automatic dialer which is playing the dtmf from a sound recorder into an automated telephone line

Comment: Back in the stone ages a telephone used a carbon microphone (300 Ohm IIRC). This page http://www.rane.com/note150.html shows the signal level as 275 mV, but I am not sure whether that refers to the incoming or outgoing signal (or maybe to both?)

Comment: It sounds like you don't even want a microphone, since there will actually be no speaking.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit below should work for you. You may have to play with values of R1, R3, and C3. Be sure to pay attention to +/- leads on the Mic. T2 and MK1 are available form http://www.mouser.com/
[image: Microphone circuit schematic]

Comment: That schematic is really really horrible! Can't you edit it a little bit so the important part of it is actually visible?

Comment: AndrejaKo, I am sorry you are having trouble viewing the schematic. You can right click on it, save it as a picture and then open it with paint or other such program, then you can zoom in in to see. I use Orcad to draw the schematics, save as a .jpg and then upload. If anyone has suggestion as how to do it better, please do let me know.

Comment: The suggestion is simple. After you export it, use a program such as Paint or even Windows Snipping tool to remove the empty part of the image. Just drag the square to select the non-empty part and then you can cut it in Paint and paste it in a new file or drag one bottom left corner of the whole image to be very small and paste the schematic back. This will give you a bigger looking schematic which would be easier to see. That's what I did when I edited your post. This way, we can immediately see the schematic, since the image will be automatically resized to fit the post size.

Comment: JPG is a bad format for monochrome line drawings, I'd save as PNG instead (or maybe even GIF) if available